# Adding static data to a CSV generated by Microsoft report builder

Tags: sql-server, csv, reporting-services

I am implementing a new service for my employer and it consumes data through CSV files SFTP'ed to a watch folder.

I am planning to do this using Report Services on SQL Server and report subscriptions to make it run periodically.

Producing the CSV is dead easy, however the CSV needs to have a set of comma delimited rows that provide configuration and instruction to the target system about the included data prepended to the generated CSV, and I cannot see how to do this header bit in report builder as I beleive that the CSV Renderer ignores the header block from the visual editor..

file header is **static** looks as follows (a bit cut down)

```
__BEGIN_CONFIG__,,,,,,,,,,
VERSION,2,,,,,,,,,,
LOOKUP_COLUMNS,LABEL-ID,,,,,,,,,,
IMPORT_COLUMNS,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
,,,,,,,,,,,,
__BEGIN_DATA__,,,,,,,,,,,
```

CSV data is placed under the `__BEGIN_DATA__` row

I have investigated altering the CSV renderer config to see if there is a directive to include a header file but I cannot see this.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: i don't think this is possible out of ssrs. you will have to export the csv.. then use poweshell or the likes to append the header section as a separate process

Comment: @Harry Thanks for your reply. This is what I fear that it cannot be done directly with SSRS, so thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible directly out of Report Server, certainly not that I have discovered